# Adding a dictionary to Aspell/Pspell

Tags: php, aspell, pspell

I have Aspell successfully installed and have compiled PHP with Pspell, and everything seems to be working fine.

The only thing I am unable to do, is create a list of "ignore" words, or a personal dictionary, however you want to refer to it.

I've tried the steps outlined [here](http://blog.samat.org/2008/11/02/creating-your-own-personal-aspell-dictionary) and [here](http://developer.mindtouch.com/MindTouch_Deki/FAQ/Editor/How_do_I...Add_words_to_the_aspell_Dictionary) but neither had any effect.

As described at the above link and on the [Aspell documentation](http://aspell.net/man-html/Format-of-the-Personal-and-Replacement-Dictionaries.html#Format-of-the-Personal-and-Replacement-Dictionaries), I tried creating a personal dictionary as outlined in the manual:

```
personal_ws-1.1 en 0
Rubiflex
quasirhombicosidodecahedron
```

I placed this in the aspell directory, my home directory, the root directory, and it was never picked up. The Aspell documentation never actually says where it should live or how to otherwise load it.

The other reference is to [creating an individual word list](http://aspell.net/man-html/Creating-an-Individual-Word-List.html#Creating-an-Individual-Word-List):

> Create a txt file with the words that you'd like to add to the dictionary, where each word is on a separate line then run the following command:
>
> ```
>  aspell --lang=en create master ./custom.rws < test.txt
> ```
>
> This will create a file called custom.rws that will contain the aspell encoded word(s) for the dictionary.  You can name the file
>   anything you want as long as the extension is .rws.  Now to add this
>   to the dictionary move the custom.rws file to the dictionary location
>   which is /usr/lib/aspell by running the following command:
>
> `cp custom.rws /usr/lib/aspell/`
>
> To finish adding it to the dictionary change into the dictionary directory by running the following:
>
> ```
>  cd /usr/lib/aspell/
>  then edit the following file: nano en_US.multi
> ```
>
> and add the following line:
>
> `add custom.rws`

Neither of these methods seemed to work and I cannot find any clear examples of how to properly add a dictionary or word list. These were the two most promising methods I was able to find and neither worked. Does anyone know how I can get Aspell to use a personal dictionary file I create?

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT**:
The [steps outlined here worked for me](http://docs.moodle.org/19/en/spell_check#Creating_Custom_Dictionaries). The are much like the ones [outlined here](http://developer.mindtouch.com/en/kb/Add_words_to_the_aspell_Dictionary) except that the latter refers to "en_US.multi" where the former refers to "en.multi". After adding the custom list to en.multi (as opposed to en_US.multi), it was working as expected.

Comment: You should actually give some examples, tell about the encoding as well and show the code how you load your dictionary.

Comment: @hakre I did give two examples, which I followed verbatim. I used the code shown on those pages to try to create and load the personal dictionary.

Comment: I meant as well an example of your dictionary file and the encoding you use for your file. Additionally, I can not open those two links, so probably you give a rough overview what you did.

Comment: @hakre I've edited my post, including the bulk of the steps used on the pages I linked.

Comment: Figured it out via an different page found on Google. Explained at the end of the OP.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer below. You can accept it later as "the answer" which will mark your question as solved (this is how this site works). Thank you for your support! And [have you seen this example? (PHP Manual)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pspell-config-create.php#example-2502)

Answer (score 2):

For my latest work onto the Perl's Text::Aspell module and code to determine the mother language of a Web visitor querying a company's search engine, I came across some of the pitfalls you describe (personal dictionary not implemented in Aspell6). However I worked it around using the 'extra-dicts' notion, one for each possible language.

I also had to workaround the fact that Aspell owns no dictionary for the Arabic, Hebrew, Japanese, Chinese and Korean languages. These languages are dealt with specifically.

You may view the full latest Perl's and bash codes for Linux and Windows running Windows/MinGW at http://vouters.dyndns.org/tima/Linux-Windows-Perl-Aspell-Determining_the_country_of_a_Web_query.html. You may use the URL links in the REFERENCES section of the document to adjust some of the Perl's code notions to PHP.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to add a personal dictonary using option *--add-extra-dicts* to aspell call

> aspell -c --add-extra-dicts=./custom.rws my_text_to_spell_check.txt

*custom.rws* has been created as depicted by OP:

> aspell --encoding=UTF-8 --lang=*<lang>* create master ./custom.rws < test.txt

And remember to add **--encoding** opton to match the correct encoding for your source file.

I Hope this can help someone!

Answer (score 0):

Using the aspell version below with Cygwin:

```
International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.6.1)
```

it was looking for a personal dictionary named `.aspell.en.pws` in my home directory, regardless of what I specified on the command line with the `--personal` option. I was able to place a symbolic link named `.aspell.en.pws` in my home directory and let it point to a different location on my file system. I had to create the file first and add the required header before aspell would start adding to my personal dictionary.

In short, you can do this:

```
echo "personal_ws-1.1 en" > ~/my/file/location.pws
ln -s ~/my/file/location.pws ~/.aspell.en.pws
```